# Vanishing of $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,N)$ vs. $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,R)$, for large $i$, where $N$ has projective dimension $1$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, local-rings

Let $M,N$ be finitely generated modules over a commutative Noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak m)$.  Assume that $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,N)=0$ for all large integers $i\gg 0$, and also that $N$ has projective  dimension $1$ ,i.e., there exists an exact sequence $0\to R^{\oplus a} \xrightarrow{f} R^{\oplus b}\to N \to 0$ where $a,b$ are positive integers and $\text{Im}(f)\subseteq \mathfrak m R^{\oplus b}$.

Then, is it true that $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,R)=0$ for all large integers $i\gg 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the long exact sequence you get by applying the $\delta$-functor $Ext_R^\cdot(M,-)$ to the short exact sequence you mentioned above. Then use the fact that $Ext_R^i(M,N)=0$ for sufficiently large values of $i$ to deduce that you have surjections $$Ext_R^i(M,R^{\oplus a})\rightarrow Ext_R^i(M,R^{\oplus b})\rightarrow 0$$for sufficiently large $i$, where the map between $Ext$ groups is induced by $f$ and hence has image in ${\frak{m}}Ext_R^i(M,R^{\oplus b})$. The latter $Ext$ group is ofcourse finitely generated as an $R$-module so Nakayama and the fact that $Ext$ is additive gives you what you want.